# How to check if a given path is possible child of another path?

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to find if given path is possible child of another path using java. Both path may not exist.

Say `c:\Program Files\My Company\test\My App` is a possible child of `c:\Program Files`.

Currently I am doing this with

```
boolean myCheck(File maybeChild, File possibleParent)
{
    return maybeChild.getAbsolutePath().startsWith( possibleParent.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can also use `java.nio.file.Path` to do this much more easily. The `java.nio.file.Path.startsWith` method seems to handle all possible cases.

Example:

```
private static void isChild(Path child, String parentText) {
    Path parent = Paths.get(parentText).toAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(parentText + " = " + child.startsWith(parent));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path child = Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/File").toAbsolutePath();
    isChild(child, "/FolderA/FolderB/File");
    isChild(child, "/FolderA/FolderB/F");
    isChild(child, "/FolderA/FolderB");
    isChild(child, "/FolderA/Folder");
    isChild(child, "/FolderA");
    isChild(child, "/Folder");
    isChild(child, "/");
    isChild(child, "");
}
```

Output:

```
/FolderA/FolderB/File = true
/FolderA/FolderB/F = false
/FolderA/FolderB = true
/FolderA/Folder = false
/FolderA = true
/Folder = false
/ = true
 = false
```

If you need more reliability you can use `toRealPath` instead of `toAbsolutePath`.

Comment: Great solution. Only possible in Java 7 or newer.

Comment: How does this handle paths with `..` in them?

Comment: The "toAbsolutePath" method resolves ".." inside the path so it should work. Better test it though.

Comment: I actually had to use `Paths.get(parentText).normalize()` in order to properly handle `..`.  `toAbsolutePath()` did not resolve them, and `toRealPath()` throws an IOException if the file doesn't exist. This worked on OSX and Centos 6.7 using Java 7.

Comment: This seems to only check against directories under root, what about Folder B, shouldn't that also be a parent?

Comment: On Windows, `C:\Program Files` is an ancestor of `C:\PROGRA~1\Foo`. Similarly, `C:\Documents and Settings` is an ancestor `C:\Users\Public`. `Path.startsWith()` doesn't handle this, so you have to call `Files.isSameFile()` at some point. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591025/1343979) tries to handle these corner cases.

Answer (score 14):

```
File parent = maybeChild.getParentFile();
while ( parent != null ) {
  if ( parent.equals( possibleParent ) )
    return true;
  parent = parent.getParentFile();
}
return false;
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Are there any holes in it?

Comment: @JoshuaD Not a hole per se, but it will return false when testing against `possibleParent` itself.  This might be what is desired or might not, depending on the use case.  (For example, testing paths to see whether they're contained under a permitted directory tree, this would fail on the root of that tree.)

Answer (score 11):

Asides from the fact the paths may not exist (and the canonicalisation may not succeed), this looks like a reasonable approach that should work in the straightforward case.

You may want to look at calling [getParentFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) on the "maybe child" in a loop, testing if it matches the parent at each step.  You can also short-circuit the comparison if the parent isn't a (real) directory.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
boolean myCheck(File maybeChild, File possibleParent) throws IOException
{
    final File parent = possibleParent.getCanonicalFile();
    if (!parent.exists() || !parent.isDirectory()) {
        // this cannot possibly be the parent
        return false;
    }

    File child = maybeChild.getCanonicalFile();
    while (child != null) {
        if (child.equals(parent)) {
            return true;
        }
        child = child.getParentFile();
    }
    // No match found, and we've hit the root directory
    return false;
}
```

Note that if you want the child relationship to be *strict* (i.e. a directory is not a child of itself) you can change the initial `child` assignment on line 9 to be `child.getParentFile()` so the first check happens on the child's containing directory.

Comment: +1 Although OP didn't state it but indeed it is likely that the question relates to actual, existing files and not paths.

Answer (score 8):

This will work for your example.  It will also return `true` if the child is a relative path
(which is often desirable.)

```
boolean myCheck(File maybeChild, File possibleParent)
{
    URI parentURI = possibleParent.toURI();
    URI childURI = maybeChild.toURI();
    return !parentURI.relativize(childURI).isAbsolute();
}
```

Comment: [Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize(java.net.URI)) says, _"If [given URI is not a child] then the given URI is returned."_ Meaning that it's probably better to change your check to `parentURI.relativize(childURI) != childURI`.  Otherwise your function gives a false positive if the `maybeChild` is an absolute path.

Comment: you're right. Probably I meant to say that if `maybeChild` were _relative_ but not a child of `possibleParent`, your method would still return `true`. But this is not actually a problem because `File.toURI()` is guaranteed to return an absolute URI, so that `childURI` is always absolute. Still, the check I proposed should work fine as well.

Comment: if `maybeChild` is relative then it can potentially be a child of anything - you cannot tell.

Comment: if `maybeChild` is absolute then it can potentially be a path from another computer, potentially running another OS. You just assume the path in question is local.  Likewise, it is natural to assume that a relative path is relative to the current working directory of the Java machine.

Answer (score 4):

That will probably work fine as it is, although I would use `getCanonicalPath()` rather than `getAbsolutePath()`. This should normalize any weird paths like `x/../y/z` which would otherwise screw up the matching.

Comment: No, no, this is **not** correct!  The questioner's `myCheck()` method, even when canonicalized, will falsely say that `C:\Prog` is a child of `C:\Program Files`.  See answer below by @biziclop.

Answer (score 4):

```
maybeChild.getCanonicalPath().startsWith( possibleParent.getCanonicalPath() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of relative paths! I think that simplest solution is  something like this:

```
public boolean myCheck(File maybeChild, File possibleParent) {
  if (requestedFile.isAbsolute) {
    return possibleParent.resolve(maybeChild).normalize().toAbsolutePath.startsWith(possibleParent.normalize().toAbsolutePath)
  } else {
    return maybeChild.normalize().toAbsolutePath.startsWith(possibleParent.normalize().toAbsolutePath)
  }
}
```

In scala you can have similar approach:

```
val baseDir = Paths.get("/home/luvar/tmp")
val baseDirF = baseDir.toFile
//val requestedFile = Paths.get("file1")
val requestedFile = Paths.get("../.viminfo")
val fileToBeRead = if (requestedFile.isAbsolute) {
  requestedFile
} else {
  baseDir.resolve(requestedFile)
}
fileToBeRead.toAbsolutePath
baseDir.toAbsolutePath
fileToBeRead.normalize()
baseDir.normalize()
val isSubpath = fileToBeRead.normalize().toAbsolutePath.startsWith(baseDir.normalize().toAbsolutePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly there is no simple, yet functional solution.

The accepted answer does consider same directories as child, which is wrong.

Here is one using *java.nio.file.Path* API only:

```
static boolean isChildPath(Path parent, Path child){
      Path pn = parent.normalize();
      Path cn = child.normalize();
      return cn.getNameCount() > pn.getNameCount() && cn.startsWith(pn);
}
```

Test cases:

```
 @Test
public void testChildPath() {
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"))).isFalse();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F/A"))).isTrue();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F/A.txt"))).isTrue();

      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F/../A"))).isFalse();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/FA"))).isFalse();

      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("FolderA"), Paths.get("FolderA"))).isFalse();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("FolderA"), Paths.get("FolderA/B"))).isTrue();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("FolderA"), Paths.get("FolderA/B"))).isTrue();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("FolderA"), Paths.get("FolderAB"))).isFalse();
      assertThat(isChildPath(Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F"), Paths.get("/FolderA/FolderB/F/Z/X/../A"))).isTrue();
}
```

Comment: Apparently, a file does lie within its own subpath. I would call the opposite result counterintuitive

Answer (score 1):

When testing paths for equality, the following considerations should be taken into account:

1. Case sensitivity of the file system. The only API which can handle case (in)sensitive file systems is *NIO.2* (1.7+), that's why neither `java.io.File` nor `String` can be used.
2. Individual path entry handling: `C:\abc` is not an ancestor, nor even an immediate parent of `C:\abcd`, hence `String.startsWith()` API can't be used.
3. On *Windows*, `C:\Program Files` is the same directory as `C:\PROGRA~1`, and `Files.isSameFile()` (from *NIO.2*) is the only API that can handle this right. This is what `Path.startsWith()` approach doesn't support.
4. Symlink friendliness (not fully covered by my answer since the actual requirements may differ). For directory symlinks, `Files.isSameFile()` supports this *to some extent*, so that `C:\Documents and Settings` **is indeed an ancestor** of `C:\Users\Public`. Again, this is where custom code works slightly better than the `Path.startsWith()` API (see [this most-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169614/1343979)).

Having said the above, the solution may look like this. Java:

```
  boolean isAncestorOf(final Path parent, final Path child) {
    final Path absoluteParent = parent.toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    final Path absoluteChild = child.toAbsolutePath().normalize();

    if (absoluteParent.getNameCount() >= absoluteChild.getNameCount()) {
      return false;
    }

    final Path immediateParent = absoluteChild.getParent();
    if (immediateParent == null) {
      return false;
    }

    return isSameFileAs(absoluteParent, immediateParent) || isAncestorOf(absoluteParent, immediateParent);
  }

  boolean isSameFileAs(final Path path, final Path path2) {
    try {
      return Files.isSameFile(path, path2);
    }
    catch (final IOException ioe) {
      return path.toAbsolutePath().normalize().equals(path2.toAbsolutePath().normalize());
    }
  }
```

Kotlin:

```
fun Path.isAncestorOf(child: Path): Boolean {
  val absoluteParent = toAbsolutePath().normalize()
  val absoluteChild = child.toAbsolutePath().normalize()

  if (absoluteParent.nameCount >= absoluteChild.nameCount) {
    return false
  }

  val immediateParent = absoluteChild.parent
                        ?: return false

  return absoluteParent.isSameFileAs(immediateParent) || absoluteParent.isAncestorOf(immediateParent)
}

fun Path.isSameFileAs(that: Path): Boolean =
  try {
    Files.isSameFile(this, that)
  }
  catch (_: NoSuchFileException) {
    toAbsolutePath().normalize() == that.toAbsolutePath().normalize()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but a pre-1.7 solution:

```
public boolean startsWith(String possibleRoot, String possibleChildOrSame) {
        String[] possiblePath = new File(possibleRoot).getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/').split("/");
        String[] possibleChildOrSamePath = new File(possibleChildOrSame).getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/').split("/");

        if (possibleChildOrSamePath.length < possiblePath.length) {
            return false;
        }

        // not ignoring case
        for (int i = 0; i < possiblePath.length; i++) {
            if (!possiblePath[i].equals(possibleChildOrSamePath[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

For completeness the java 1.7+ solution:

```
public boolean startsWith(String possibleRoot, String possibleChildOrSame) {
        Path p1 = Paths.get(possibleChildOrSame).toAbsolutePath();
        Path p2 = Paths.get(possibleRoot).toAbsolutePath();
        return p1.startsWith(p2);
}
```