# Serving file resources contents from subfolder safely, securely

Tags: java, security, file-io

A user can submit a subfolder/filename to download.

The subfolder/filename will **then be used to serve a file** from a predertemined folder.

In the end, I am doing `new File(folder, "subfolder/filename")`.

But before I do that, I also check that `!"subfolder/filename".contains("..")`

**But is this enough?** Is there possibly a scenario where two dots (..) may not come after each other, but still be interpreted as two dots when passed to new File(...) ?

Are there any other way a user can navigate back and reach content outside this folder?

**Do you need to do something else to secure such a subfolder/filename access from folder?**

Comment: "...from a predetermined folder."  Might be more thorough to ensure that the folder requested is actually a child of the root folder they can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can get the absolute paths, from the OS, so a bit slow.

```
String folderPath = folder.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator;
File file = new File(folder, "subfolder/filename");
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();

if (!path.startsWith(folderPath)) {
    log(Level.ERROR, "Security breach attempt: ...");
    return;
}
```

A simple check would probably do too:

```
Pattern BREACH = Pattern.compile("\\.[\\\\]*\\.");
if (BREACH.matcher(path).find()) { ... }
```

Mind when you use version control or other "protected" files/folders, then names of files or folders starting with a dot are illegal too.

Comment: I also found this just now, accepted answer. What do you think of that approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746671/how-to-check-if-a-given-path-is-possible-child-of-another-path

Comment: @momo Fine too. Canonical would do a bit more, but that seems irrelevant. And Path/Paths is more modern.

Comment: I trust `getCanonicalPath`'s ability to resolve ambiguities a lot more than any pattern matching; also, if `folderPath` is guaranteed to be a folder's canonical path, then the link by @momo is essentially equivalent

Comment: Also if one does not take care, a user might first _upload_ a file `aa...bb.txt` (dots inside), and one has to decide whether to check for `/..` and so on. File names are a bit more dangerous if passed to C or perl, where pipe operators might effect something on open calls and such.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute something like

```
cd ./\.\.
```

In Unix it will change directory to parent. May be You can resolve file and when check if it under right parent?

UPD: looks like in java You cannot use \.\. pattern http://goo.gl/4Rszg5 still it does not mean what check for ".." is sufficient. Better check canonical path