# regex to disallow access to parent directories - java

Tags: java, regex, directory

So what I need is to create a regex which is going to be used on my server to make sure that all the files that the user is requesting access to, are under a specific directory. Let's name that dir `UserFiles` and let's assume that it is under the path `/Server/Users/Bob/UserFiles`.

So now when a client sends a request to read a file I want to validate that the path that he is asking access to is under `/Bob/UserFiles/`.

I thought about making sure that the prefix of the path always begins with `/Userfiles/` and that there is no `..` in the path (so that would also protect me from restricted access like `/UserFiles/../../noAccess.txt`)

examples of not allowed inputs:

`C:/UserFiles/`

`../../Alice/txt.txt`

`/UserFiles/../../noAccess.txt`

examples of allowed input:

`/UserFiles/UserFiles/Alice/txt.txt`

`/UserFiles/txt.txt`

`/UserFiles/Bob/Bob/txt.txt`

I cannot think of any cases why this wouldn't work. I also tried to build the regex but it is not quite right as it allows inputs like `/UserFiles//txt.txt` (Might allow even more that it shouldn't that I have no knowledge of)

So is my idea complete or there are other cases I havent thought of? If my idea is complete could you please help me fix my regex?

`(?!\.\.)^\/UserFiles\/[/\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about resolving the path and checking only afterwards (note, the behaviour is OS-dependent):

```
new File(input).getCanonicalPath().startsWith("/UserFiles/")
```

Or, depending on how to interpret your question:

```
new File(input).getCanonicalPath().startsWith("/Server/Users/Bob/UserFiles/")
```

Comment: havent really thought of that solution. I am not sure how CanonicalPaths are working but I can give it a go and leave some feedback. thanks

Comment: Strings version of `startsWith("/UserFiles")` may also allow access to directories of names `UsersFilesFoo`. It is little safer to use `startsWith("/UserFiles/")`. Also I am not sure how `getCanonicalPath` will behave on server. Maybe it is better to create canonical path of `/Server/Users/Bob/UserFiles` and canonical path of path provided by user as compared using `childPath.startsWith(parentPath)` as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746671/how-to-check-if-a-given-path-is-possible-child-of-another-path

Comment: @Pshemo: Good input. Fixed. I was actually wary of all the infosec things that I might overlook in an answer here...

Comment: So as it concerns my example you actually mean

`new File(input).getCanonicalPath().startsWith("/Server/Users/Bob/UserFiles/")` right?

Comment: @Rakim it depends on what you meant in your question :) if you remove ambiguity, I'll fix my answer

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, I think that the right answer would be the one of my previous comment. Well my implementation was a bit more complicated but using your pointers I managed to make it work. I dont really know how to edit my question to make it more clear but you were on point anyway Thanks