# Extracted ZIP file failed - No files inside, and having .zip25 extension after extract

Tags: java, zip, extract, unzip

I was trying to extract the ZIP file from my Linux, I'm able to extract it, but the expected output is failing/wrong. The extract file suddenly has no files inside and the folder extracted has .zip25 extension. I searched on this, and there is saying that it is corrupted. However, I don't think it is corrupted because I am able to open and extract the zip files perfectly in local (Windows directory).

Example:

Zip file: FolderZip.zip

After extract: FolderZip.zip25 (Note: This is already extracted but still has .zip25 extension, also the files inside are missing).

Below is my code, I've worked on this for almost a month, but still can't figure it out. Can someone help me to figure out what did I do wrong?

```java
public void unZipFolder(String zipFile, String outputFolder){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        System.out.println("ZipFileLocation: " + zipFile);
        LOG.info(" ZipFileLocation: " + zipFile);

        File folder = new File(outputFolder);
        if(!folder.exists())folder.mkdirs();

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            
            while(ze != null) {
                new File(folder.getParent()).mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(folder);
                File newFile = new File(outputFolder + FilenameUtils.indexOfLastSeparator(ze.getName()));
                                
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    if (!newFile.isDirectory() && !newFile.mkdirs()) {
                        throw new IOException("Failed to create directory " + newFile);
                    }else if(ze.isDirectory()){
                        newFile.mkdirs();
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println("File Unzip: " + newFile);
                        LOG.info(" File Unzip: " + newFile);
                        newFile.mkdirs();
                        fos.close();
                        zis.closeEntry();
                        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                    }
                }    
                
                boolean result = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(zipFile));
                if (result) {
                    System.out.println("ZipFile is deleted....");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unable to delete the file.....");
              }
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();
            fis.close();
         }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: `FilenameUtils.indexOfLastSeparator(ze.getName())` most likely returns a number, you presumably want to pass that number as argument to `ze.getName().substring()` or some such. You didn't include this method, you didn't include how you call this, hence, not really possible to help you any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to be able to tell you exactly what's wrong with your code, but `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(folder);` throws an exception because, well, `folder` is, a directory, so you can't write to it.

I'm also scratching my head over what your expecting `new File(folder.getParent()).mkdirs();` to do.

I basically threw out your code and started again with...

```
public void unZipFolder(File zipFile, File outputFolder) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    System.out.println("ZipFileLocation: " + zipFile);
    System.out.println("outputFolder = " + outputFolder);

    if (!outputFolder.exists() && !outputFolder.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to create output folder: " + outputFolder);
    } else if (outputFolder.exists() && !outputFolder.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IOException("Output is not a directory: " + outputFolder);
    }

    try (ZipFile zipper = new ZipFile(zipFile)) {
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipper.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry ze = entries.nextElement();
            File destination = new File(outputFolder, ze.getName());
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                if (!destination.exists() && !destination.mkdirs()) {
                    throw new IOException("Could not create directory: " + destination);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Writing " + destination);
                try (InputStream is = zipper.getInputStream(ze); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
                    // You could use is.transferTo(fos) here but I'm a grump old coder
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4];
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what's important to know about this is, it expects the directory contents of the zip files to be relative (ie no root directory information).  If your zip file does contain root directory information (ie `C:/...` or `/...`), then you're going to need to clean that up yourself.

Now, if you have trouble with this, I would suggest commenting out the "extraction" portion of the code and placing in more `System.out.println` statements

## `transferTo`

After reading through the code for `transferTo`, it's basically doing the same thing that the code example above is doing - so, if you wanted to reduce the code complexity (and reduce the risk of possible bugs), you could use it - been some what old school, I'd probably still do it the "old way" in order to provide support for progress monitoring of some kind - but that's beyond the scope of the question.

## "Security issues"

This ones a little harder to tie down, as no solution is 100% safe.

I modified the above code to use something like...

```
Path parent = outputFolder.toPath().toAbsolutePath();
String name = "../" + ze.getName();
Path child = parent.resolveSibling(new File(outputFolder, name).toPath());
```

And this ended up throwing a `NoSuchFileException`, so, at least you could "fail fast", assuming that's what you want.

You might also consider removing `..`, leading `/` or leading path specifications in an attempt to make the path "relative", but that could become complicated as something like `somePath/../file` could still be valid within your use case.

Comment: For throwing it all out, this isn't very good. Tossing the use of `ZipInputStream` is a tad harsh. Why isn't this using `.transferTo`? ;pca ;var `buffer` isn't doing anything. It's trivial (especially if you use the new path API) to double check that the target path is a sub-path of the outputFolder and thus close the gaping security hole that this code has.

Comment: @rzwitserloot By all means, show me a better solution, please, I'm old school

Comment: @rzwitserloot One reason for NOT using `Reader#transferTo` is that it doesn't provide the means for providing progression callbacks - while not included in this example, I like my APIs to provide some kind of progression feedback especially when performing I/O operations

Comment: @rzwitserloot `File destination = new File(outputFolder, ze.getName());` would make `destination` always a subpath of `outputFolder` - but, I may be missing your point

Comment: @MadProgrammer This works to me, I add delete condition for the zip file once already extracted. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I shove some `..` in the second parameter of the `File(String, String)` constructor, guess what happens? Progress is a lot more complicated than what you're making it out to be, and various good solutions exist based on piped streams which are entirely compatible with `.transferTo`. And, we're talking about `InputStream.transferTo`, not `Reader`.

Comment: @Euphoria this code is a security issue. If you unzip any zip you don't trust with it, you're going to get your box p0wned.

Comment: @rzwitserloot *"If you unzip any zip you don't trust with it"* - Then what's the solution? *"If I shove some .. in the second parameter"* - garbage in, garbage out.  It's not always entirely possible to protected against every stupid thing a user might do - but again, show me, don't tell me - provide your answer and you can help teach two people today

Comment: @rzwitserloot Interestingly, I looked into the `transferTo` code and it's basically doing the same thing that my code is doing (using 8k instead of 4k as the default buffer size) - so, what is the benefit, apart from not having to actually write the code?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746671/how-to-check-if-a-given-path-is-possible-child-of-another-path, `System.out.println(Paths.get("UnZipped/..").toAbsolutePath().startsWith(Paths.get("UnZipped/").toAbsolutePath()));` prints `true`, which is obviously not what we want - so I'm obviously missing something there

Comment: @rzwitserloot Bit of running around, but `System.out.println(Paths.get("UnZipped/..").toRealPath().startsWith(Paths.get("UnZipped/").toRealPath()));` does work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yup, combine real path + `startsWith`. The benefit of using `transferTo` should be obvious. Let the JDK's implementation take care of it. The thing with the buffer and the discussion about how large it should be are all sorts of details that are irrelevant.

Comment: @rzwitserloot *"The benefit of using transferTo should be obvious. Let the JDK's implementation take care of it."* - Except when it was introduced it was the slowest option , although I think it has been fixed, at least in openJDK.  If there's one thing I've learnt over time is, the JDK implementations aren't always the best, but neither is mine - it's balancing act. *"combine real path + startsWith"* - I'm still missing the point - show, don't tell - have an example, another SO answer, blog, anything? These comments are otherwise wasting everyone's time - sorry, I'm all sorts of dumb

Comment: @rzwitserloot Might as well just say go use [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) and be done with it, but where's the fun in that 

Comment: That's the point of core JDK libraries. If they are slow today they'll get faster tomorrow. In contrast to apache library impls which are nearly obsolete by the time apache releases them and get worse from there. It's not a balancing act, you don't re-invent JDK core functionality unless you have extremely good reason to do so.

Comment: @rzwitserloot With all due respect that is your opinion - I don't disagree with you, but it is an opinion.  And over the last 30 years of front end development, when it comes to transferring data, I like to do it by hand so I can get my own progress feedback - not always the same way, but that's just how I role - in the context of this question, yes, `transferTo` is probably the better choice

Comment: @MadProgrammer however, is it possible to extract the zip files without the folder? I mean, once it is extracted the files inside would be shown without the folder

Comment: @Euphoria So, if you didn't want to preserve the internal structure, you could just trim of the path elements of the `ZipEntry#name`, hostly, you don't actually need the that, you can name the extracted file anything you want, that's up to you

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see, everything clear now. Thanks for the help, appreciate your effort! :)